# why my int change in the middle of c++ programm?

Tags: c++, clion

I have written the code below. The matter is this: after I read the `x` and `y` from input stream there is not matter - mean `x` and `y` are the exact value of input - but later they change to some other value.

what's the matter?  I can not understand it!!

```
int count(char s[], char ss[] , long long int posF, long long int posE){}
int main()
{
    char s[]{};
    int q = 0;
    cin >> s;
    cin >> q;
    int choise = 0;
    while(q--)
    {
        cin>>choise;
        if(choise == 1)
        {
            int x = 0;
            cin>>x;
            char c;
            cin>>c;
            s[x-1] = c;
        }
        else if(choise == 2)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            cin>>x>>y;
            //Fist LOG
            cout<<"First log x and y are correct    "<<x<<"  "<<y<<endl;
            char ss[]{};
            cin>>ss;
            //Second LOG
            cout<<"Second log x and y are  wrong?Why?"<<x<<"  "<<y;
            cout<<count(s, ss, x-1, y-1)<<endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char s[]{};` and `char ss[]{};` are not legal c++. Even if your compiler offers extensions allowing it, the lines `cin >> s;` and `cin>>ss;` will almost certainly be undefined behavior.

Comment: Answer is simple: Undefined behavior. Most likely due to referencing items out of bounds of your arrays.

Comment: I dont know what you're trying to do with `char ss[]{}; cin>>ss;` but im pretty sure its wrong.

Comment: `>>` to a `char` array is risky at the best of times, and a zero length array is about the worst of times.There is no overflow protection.

Comment: @Ron  when i delete {}   it says me that (local incomplete array must be initialize )

Comment: @m1350 Sounds like you could benefit from reading one of [these C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Borgleader when I comment cin>>ss;  it becomes ok what should i do?

Comment: @m1350: Programming by guessing doesn't work. You are going to have to take a break for learning the language from one of [these C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado [You sure about that?](http://ideone.com/BblXXD) The OP is confused enough as it is.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Even if your suggest's syntax was valid, the proposed solution is overly complex and not robust. For c++ questions, it would be better to stick with idiomatic solutions, such as using `std::string` to store strings.

Comment: Replace `char []` with `std::string`.  Replace `cin >> ss` with `std::getline(cin, string_variable)`.  You could also read single words with `cin >> string_variable;`.

Comment: Use a `switch` instead of an `if-else` ladder.  For example, your ladder is missing a final `else` clause.  What happens when the User enters `4` as a *choise*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other said the problem of your code is char `ss[]{};cin>>ss;` so if you comment if you will understand it

so my suggestion is to use string instead of char[] and you can use `cin<<` for string and you can use [] operator e.x

```
string s = "Code";
cout<<s[0];
```

and M.r @Ron is correct it's better to read [This Books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)